# Windows 10 getting slower

Tags: windows, windows-10, lag

I have newly installed windows 10 on my laptop and before linking the computer to my microsoft account, the computer would boot up fast and would take little to no time in getting from the login window to main desktop. Now there is a considerable lag and the screen remains dark for maybe half a minute until the desktop appears. Also after the desktop appears the start menu and taskbar take some more time before starting to respond. It's obvious to me that linking my microsoft account is the main culprit here.

I was getting irritated with the fact that I couldn't login to my computer without an internet connection so I disabled the option to ask for a password when logging in. Maybe it has something to do with it? Can I do anything about it?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes of activity after boot. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze why you have a lag

Comment: have you captured the trace? Otherwise I can't help?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a lot of junk files, temporary files or memory dumps. You can check most of these through:

```
Settings > System > Storage > This PC (C:) >
```

And then click on parts to view and delete them.